# how to check log per user in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

There are 3 users in Jenkins, Is it possible to check which user in Jenkins delete build history or not?

Information in log doesn't clear for me and I don't understand any thing.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Go to -> **Manage Jenkins** -> **System Log**

Click on add new and name it something for example ->

[image]

**-> user_access_details**

Then click on add loggers once prompted and add **jenkins.security.SecurityListener** and set it to Finest level

[image]